# ListView custom button does not update pulled in selected ids

Tags: apex, visualforce, list-button

I am struggling to figure out what I am missing for my code to work as expected. I have a visualforce that is tied to a button that just is used to mass update a status. This button is supposed to take the selected records and then update them to declined if it is not already declined. It will show me the visualforce page with the records, The debug log shows the ids and the queries but nothing happens.

VF:

```
    <apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="File_Feed__c" extensions="FileFeedController" recordSetVar="file_feeds" action="{!declineFileFeedRecords}" cache="true"  >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Files for Reject" id="muselectedlist">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!updateFileFeeds}" value="Confirm"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="fileFeeds" id="mutab">
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.id}" id="fileFeedId"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Account__c}" id="fileFeedAccount"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Action_Type__c}" id="fileFeedActionType"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Status__c}" id="fileFeedStatus"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class FileFeedController 
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;

    public FileFeedController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }

    public PageReference declineFileFeedRecords()
    {       
        // Get the selected records
        List<File_Feed__c> selectedFileFeeds = [SELECT Account__c,Action_Type__c,Field_Updating__c,Id,Name,New_Value__c,Old_Value__c,Status__c 
                                                    FROM File_Feed__c 
                                                    WHERE id IN : (List<File_Feed__c>) standardController.getSelected()];
        // Update records       
        for(File_Feed__c selectedFileFeed : selectedFileFeeds)
        {
            if(selectedFileFeed.Status__c != 'Declined') 
                selectedFileFeed.Status__c = 'Declined';
        }       

        return null;        
    }

    public PageReference updateFileFeeds()
    {       
        return standardController.save();   
    }
}
```

Configuration of the Button:

[image: Configuration of the Button:]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in this method `declineFileFeedRecords` you're not actually updating the records. Please, add `update selectedFileFeeds;` before return statement and put this whole code to `updateFileFeeds` method (you don't need the `declineFileFeedRecords` one). Also no need for `action="{!declineFileFeedRecords}"` in VF page. And you don't need to select fields in SOQL for `selectedFileFeeds` to show them in `pageBlockTable`, because they are automatically retrieved with `standardController` functionality.

So the final result will look like:

**VF Page**:

```
<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" standardController="File_Feed__c" extensions="FileFeedController" recordSetVar="file_feeds" cache="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Files for Reject" id="muselectedlist">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!updateFileFeeds}" value="Confirm"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="fileFeeds" id="mutab">
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.id}" id="fileFeedId"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Account__c}" id="fileFeedAccount"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Action_Type__c}" id="fileFeedActionType"/>
                <apex:column value="{!fileFeeds.Status__c}" id="fileFeedStatus"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**:

```
public with sharing class FileFeedController
{
    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController;

    public FileFeedController(ApexPages.StandardSetController standardController)
    {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }

    public PageReference updateFileFeeds()
    {
        // Get the selected records
        List<File_Feed__c> selectedFileFeeds = [SELECT Status__c
        FROM File_Feed__c
        WHERE id IN : (List<File_Feed__c>) standardController.getSelected()];
        // Update records       
        for(File_Feed__c selectedFileFeed : selectedFileFeeds)
        {
            if(selectedFileFeed.Status__c != 'Declined')
                selectedFileFeed.Status__c = 'Declined';
        }
        update selectedFileFeeds;
        return standardController.save();
    }
}
```